# Blackberry Dev - Preverifying error

Tags: blackberry, preverify

I got an error while I tried to preverify my lib. It seems to me that the SDK could not find the default Java lib though I had added it into the system.

Here is the command::

> D:\Work\Setup\Blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\compon
>   ents\bin>preverify.exe -classpath ..\lib\net_rim_api.jar  encryption.jar

And here is the error

> Error preverifying class com.wavesecure.encryption.EncryptionManager
>   VERIFIER ERROR com/wavesecure/encryption/EncryptionManager.encrypt([B[B)[B:
>   Cannot find class java/security/Key

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it looks like `EncryptionManager` references java.security.Key which is part of Java SE, but there's no `java.security` package in the RIM API.  Are you sure `encryption.jar` is a BlackBerry compatibile jar file?  Maybe there's a BlackBerry specific version you can get?